# Unable to access DOM elements in Firefox Add-on content script

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, content-script

Using Firefox 34 and addon SDK 1.17.

I am using the SDK's page-mod to attach a content script. Inside the content script I am seeing very weird behaviour when trying to access DOM elements.

main.js

```
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "somewebsite",
    contentScriptWhen: 'end',
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("stuff.js")]
});
```

stuff.js

```
log(document.getElementsByTagName("body")); // empty object
log(document.getElementById("SomeIdThatShouldBeThere")); // empty object
log(document.getElementsByTagName("li")); // x amount of empty objects...
```

This will however work as expected:

```
document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
```

Also for the empty objects that I get I can do

```
obj.style.border = ...
```

and it will work, the html element is seen to change border colour etc. But I am not able to read the properties of the elements, so I am working blind.

I have read people say there are some restrictions to modifying DOM from content scripts, but I am not able to do even the most basic thing apparently. Is this supposed to be supported or not then?

edit: Eventually I noticed that the elements are in their correct places and I can read their properties, but logging an element will still only ever print an empty object... Meaning every desired property of an element has to be printed separately. At least it works, but could be better.

Comment: Have you tried using `unsafeWindow.document` instead of `document` ?

Comment: It does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: BTW you have a typo in your code. It should be `getElementById`, not `getElementsById` (notice the `s`). But I can't figure out why the `getElementsByTagName` returns empty objects. Are you seeing these empty objects in the console?

Comment: The typo is my mistake when typing the question, so not relevant to the actual issue. The objects are empty in the console as well. I'm using firebug, when logging an element that I get from getElementById for example, it looks:  Object {}. Clicking the object shows: "There are no properties to show for this object." As I added in the edit though, I am able to access the properties after all, just inconvenient because I can't simply print an element.

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery or some other library?

Comment: Only jQuery, it also returned only empty objects. From your questions I get the impression that this definitely should not happen. I raised the question in firefox addon developement irc-channels as well, but it attracted no interest at the time (possibly because of holidays)

Comment: Don't use jQuery for a plugin. What do you mean by "x amounts of empty objects"? Are you saying there are no objects, or that there are x number of elements? Remember, that gives a "live list", so if the elements aren't there when the call is invoked, they'll still show up when you view them in the console.

Comment: squint: I get the actual amount of elements that should be present on the page. Just when I print a single element, it looks like an empty object which doesn't have any properties. The properties can still be accessed normally though

Comment: Dunno if you ended up getting anywhere with this, but I'm having the same problem and doing a bit more research I'm suspecting it has to do with how content scripts are insulated from the DOM https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Accessing_the_DOM

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output an object from the dom to the console use:

```
unsafeWindow.console.log(document.getElementById("SomeIdThatShouldBeThere"));
// Or map it in your contentscript file for less typing
var log = unsafeWindow.console.log;
log(document.getElementById("SomeIdThatShouldBeThere"));
```

This also works without having to go in to the about:config and adding the preference "extensions.sdk.console.logLevel" with a value of "all", so you can log any message you want.

However, if your also running the sdk cmd console, this will output an error, but I don't think it's anything to worry about, all code executes without a problem.

**Edit:**
Just found out when I mapped it to var log, if firebug console was not open it would cause the add-on to stop working, and still did not work when having firefox console open. However doing a strait unsafeWindow.console.log(foo) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. It makes basic scripting much more cumbersome.

Try this (from http://louisremi.com/2011/12/07/mozilla-addons-interactions-between-content-scripts-and-pages/)

"**Inline Script Injection**

The right way of doing so is to inject inline scripts in the page and/or use customEvents. Inline scripts are a third level of scripts that can be used to create variables or functions in the global scope:

```
// Quotes nesting would be a real mess now,
// let's use a separate file loaded as a contentScriptFile
var script = document.createElement( "script" );
script.innerHTML = "var test =" + JSON.stringify( anyValue )+";";
document.body.appendChild( script );
```

Validation of this code will output warnings, as addons shouldn’t create script tags. But this is still the safest alternative to the unsafeWindow.

**customEvents**

customEvents are very similar to mouse events, except that they are programmatically triggered, and that they can transport arbitrary (jsonable) data between content scripts and pages, in both directions:

```
// inline script in example.com/index.html
var evt = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
evt.initCustomEvent( "transData", true, false, jsonableValue );
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
// in contentScript.js
window.addEventListener( "transData", function( event ) {
  // the data is available in the detail property of the event
  self.port.emit( "transData", event.detail );
});"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue in my add-on's content script.  For some unknown reason the `object`'s  values can be printed to the console if you copy them to a new object.  You can create a simple function as a workaround:

```
function getLoggableObject(obj){
    var loggable={};
    for(var key in obj){
        loggable[key]=obj[key];
    }
    return loggable;
}
```

Here's an example of calling this function:

```
 console.log("default  : ", $("table")[0]);
 console.log("loggable : ", getLoggableObject($("table")[0]));
```

And the output of those log statements:

```
"default  : " Object {  }
"loggable : " Object { createCaption: "function createCaption() {
    [native code]
}", deleteCaption: "function deleteCaption() {
    [native code]
}", createTHead: "function createTHead() {
    [native code]
}", deleteTHead: "function deleteTHead() {
    [native code]
}", createTFoot: "function createTFoot() {
    [native code]
}", deleteTFoot: "function deleteTFoot() {
    [native code]
}", createTBody: "function createTBody() {
    [native code]
}", insertRow: "function insertRow() {
    [native code]
}", deleteRow: "function deleteRow() {
    [native code]
}", caption: null, 210 more… }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
log(document.getElementsByTagName("body")); // empty object
log(document.getElementById("SomeIdThatShouldBeThere")); // empty object
log(document.getElementsByTagName("li")); // x amount of empty objects...
```

To be this:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("body")); // empty object
console.log(document.getElementById("SomeIdThatShouldBeThere")); // empty object
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("li")); // x amount of empty objects...
```

Comment: I did var log = console.log; in the beginning. But I will try it anyway once I get home, never know.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It did not make a difference